# Is it possible to convert a LongText to hexadecimal in MySQl

Tags: mysql

I have a column, say col1, of type LongText and it contains a long integer number: ex: 1233456777.....etc. I need to convert this number to hexadecimal and insert it into a new column, say col2. Is this possible in MySQL ? How?

I have tried to export the longtext values to text file, convert it using Java, but I am having hard time to update the records with the new hexadecimal. Please, help me.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
UPDATE myDatabase SET col2 = HEX(col1);
```

This will take the value of col1, return the HEX version of that and place it in col2, for all rows in myDatabase.
Make sure you have the correctly sized definition for col2.  IF HEX() doesn't take LONGTEXT, perhaps you can use CONVERT...

```
UPDATE myDatabase SET col2 = HEX(CONVERT(col1, CHAR(255)));
```

Comment: It didn't work with me. Ex: I have the following values: 12, 15 they have been converted to: 3132, 3135. Please, not that my columns are longtext and I need this type because the actual numbers are going to be long. This is only a toy example.

Comment: My decimal number is longer than 255. That's why I used longtext. Is there any solution ?

Comment: I used: `hex(CONVERT(pk, CHAR(4294967295)));` with is the maximum length of longtext type. But the conversion is not done correctly.

Comment: I guess then that BIGINT (2^63) will not hold the decimal value of your longtext.  In this case, I suppose I would do what you are trying, converting to hex outside of MySQL. I would export using a format like: SELECT * FROM myDB INTO OUTFILE 'foo.txt'; creating a tab separated file. Operate on col1, creating col2, and import using LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'bar.txt' INTO TABLE myNewTable;